# Trying to supply an alternative implementation for Spring's FilterChainProxy

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm working on an application using Spring security.
The application is extensible and I would like to block extensions from programmatically changing the filters in the filter chain map of Spring's `FilterChainProxy`. What I intend to do is the following:

1. Implement a `CustomFilterChainProxy` implementing all of `FilterChainProxy`'s implemented interfaces (Filter, InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware). In it I will hold a private `FilterChainProxy` member and delegate all of the interface calls to it.
2. Use Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` by declaring in the `web.xml` file:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>customSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```
3. In the Spring configuration files, instead of using Spring's `FilterChainProxy` directly I will have my bean have the `CustomFilterChainProxy` as its class, as follows:

   ```
   <bean id="customSecurityFilterChain" class="....CustomFilterChainProxy">
       <security:filter-chain-map ...>
           <security:filter-chain pattern="..." filters="..." />
           <security:filter-chain pattern="..." filters="..." />
           ...
       </security:filter-chain-map>
   </bean>
   ```
4. In order to be able to set the filter chain map during Spring bean loading I must supply a setter in my `CustomFilterChainProxy` class. That I will do. And in order to prevent setting the filter chain map after Spring bean loading I will make sure that after bean construction (in a `@PostConstruct` method) an exception will be thrown from that setter.

By having a `CustomFilterChainProxy` instead of a `FilterChainProxy`, am I causing any Spring process to malfunction?

I saw the only Spring class referencing the `FilterChainProxy` object itself is `FilterChainProxyPostProcessor` but couldn't find out if this should affect my implementation choice. Any input?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unlikely to be sufficient to protect you from malicious extension code.

If the extension can access your bean, then it can also just access the original `FilterChainProxy` through the `ApplicationContext`. In fact, it can probably access any other bean in the same configuration, so it could potentially:

- Load user account data, including passwords
- Modify or read settings on other beans to break the system
- Use reflection to read instance fields directly
- Modify the current security context
- Lots of other nasty things depending on what you are using

If you have untrusted code in your app then you would need to use a `SecurityManager` to prevent this kind of thing and you can then also prevent access to Spring Security classes. Configuring a `SecurityManager` can be a pain, but it's probably the only option if you have code you don't trust running in the same VM.

**Update:** If your only concern is preventing anyone from calling the `setFilterChainMap` method then overriding this method will obviously prevent anyone from accidentally calling this through a reference to your bean (this method is actually deprecated in 3.1 in favour of a constructor. However, it's not clear from your question why someone would obtain a reference to your instance rather than the original bean, or why this is your main concern. The `FilterChainProxy` is not normally accessed by user code in an application. To do so, you'd have to explicitly request it from the bean factory.

Comment: +1. Trying to prevent usages through this type of code-hiding will not stop someone with truly malicious intent but it will frustrate everyone else using your framework as you're deliberately circumventing the (established) API.

Comment: @user1095833 I guess it's not really clear how you're using Spring Security from your post. Are you building everything in code or using an ApplicationContext? Normally the only way to access the FilterChainProxy is by explicitly getting the bean from the ApplicationContext. Or do you have a use which involves an extension making use of a reference to the FilterChainProxy?

Comment: Yes, my only concern is preventing from calling setFilterChainMap - that's because we found extension code accessing the bean directly and using this setter. Updated the question to show Spring's configuration file. It configures a CustomFilterChainProxy instead of FilterChainProxy so referencing the bean will return it a CustomFilterChainProxy.

Comment: If you are configuring the FilterChainProxy as a bean, rather than using namespace configuration, then it shouldn't make any different if you use a custom class, provided you don't alter the behaviour in any other way.